# Connect Microsoft SQL with Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, connect

I'm working on my project where I have to connect Microsoft SQL with Java. I want to pull information from my database. I keep getting this error:

```
 SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.<init>(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1011)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at SendEmails.main(SendEmails.java:22)
```

Something is wrong with my Driver. I can not figure it out what. Maybe I have wrong path or something else. Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SendEmails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        String dbName = "Student";
        String serverip="109.45.100.100";
        String serverport="1433";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverip+"\\SQLEXPRESS:"+serverport+";databaseName="+dbName+"";
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
        String databaseUserName = "student";
        String databasePassword = "admin";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUserName, databasePassword);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            result = null;
            String pa,us;
            result = stmt.executeQuery("Select Top 45 * From Students ");

            while (result.next()) {
                us=result.getString("uname");
                pa = result.getString("pass");              
                System.out.println(us+"  "+pa);
            }

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone knows what is wrong with my code please let me know.

Comment: Have you included the corresponding JDBC library in your project?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if its right.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing jar file in your classpath.

set classpath to `sqlserverjdbc.jar`.

which contains `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.sqlserverdriver` class.

First check whether your jar file containing `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` or `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.sqlserverdriver` class.

[Check system requirements here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422(v=sql.110).aspx)

[Both jdk 7 and jdk 8 compatible jar file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx)

Comment: You can take a look I edited my question. Now I'm getting this error.

Comment: @user3023588, its a driver version problem. I think you are using jdk 8. so compatible driver jar here you need to use.

Comment: After I downloaded jdbc 4.2 I got my connection. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

As exception says "`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"`.

So either required jar is not present or there is problem with path of included jar.

Download jar from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx and add this jar as an dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working sample

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectMSSQLServer
{
   public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string,
            String db_userid,
            String db_password)
   {
      try {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string,
                  db_userid, db_password);
         System.out.println("connected");
         Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
         String queryString = "select * from sysobjects where type='u'";
         ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
         while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ConnectMSSQLServer connServer = new ConnectMSSQLServer();
      connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname>", "<user>",
               "<password>");
   }
}
```

Look that you added a `.newInstance()` call not present in this example. Replace `<hostname>`, `<user>` and `<password>` with appropiate values.

**ADDED REFERENCE**

[Download driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx)

Comment: I'm still getting error. You can take a look I edited up in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I cant test since I havent SQL Server installed